# Variables communication between differents useEffect of the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Reactjs component where I use hooks. In this component I have two useEffect, in the first one I rescue the cookies and do the fetch for data request and subsequent saving, and in the second useEffect I operate with the data (sum, filter, etc.)

In the first useEffect I save the json response in this form:

```
const data = response.json();
```

And in the other useEffect I need to make a copy of that data to be able to operate with the data without losing it, and I have stated:

```
const operationData = data;
```

However, in the second useEffect the data variable isn't recognized because it has been declared in the first useEffect.
I can't use useState because the graph models are made with React classes and take the data from the first data read from my component, and reads null.

I need to communicate the data variable of the first useEffect with the second useEffect to be able to match operationData to that variable.

Comment: why aren't you doing both of the operations in the same useEffect

Comment: Because the second useEffect is rendered every time the value of a filter changes and if every time it changes it makes the data request in the browser it is very slow

Comment: can you store cookies in a context or a parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) to store mutable data that don't update the state:

```
const data = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // [...]
  data.current = response.json();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  const operationData = data.current;
}, []);
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize data.current at the second useEffect. It appears "undefined"

Comment: @acp Are you sure the first `useEffect()` already stored the response? I tested this code and it works.

Comment: Yes, the first useEffect store the response and if I add a console.log("1", data.current) at the start of the second useEffect it doesn't recognize it, only recognize data, but data is an object.

Comment: @acp Please make a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(finalUrl, options);
                
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(
            DefaultLanguage.messages.errors.requestError `${response.status}`
          ); 
        }
        
        data.current = await response.json();
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getData()
  }, []);

Comment: useEffect(() => 
    {
     const operationsData = async () => {
       try {

        const operationData = data.current;
   
       } catch (err) {
         setError(err.message);
         setSeries(null);  
       }
      }
     operationsData();
  }, [])

Comment: These are my two useEffect and before that I have declared const data = useRef();

Comment: @acp Can you put this in your question instead of the comments please?

Comment: @acp It doesn't work because the second `useEffect` runs before you get the response of your fetch: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-yonath-ny3yf1?file=/src/App.js:891-908

Comment: What should I do in this case?

Comment: @acp Maybe you could move the function `operationsData()` out of the second  `useEffect` and call it in the first `useEffect` once you have the response?

Comment: Could you give me an example, please?

Comment: @acp I've updated the example on CodeSandbox.

Comment: And how could I stop the data.current re-render? Because it doesn't stop at console and I only need call it once.

Comment: I mean, I only need fetch request ejecution once.

Comment: @acp I'm not sure to understand what you mean, maybe you should post a new question if this one is solved

Comment: Okay I will post it. Thank you so much

Comment: Arkellys, I have posted my problem in another publication. Could you help me?

Comment: @acp I can take a look but I don't see any other questions on your profile.

Comment: I've just repost the question

Comment: @acp Sorry, I don't think I can help you with your other question, it seems complex and I don't really have the time

Comment: Not problem. Thank you so much anyway.